# Is it ok to use two different ReactJS Code bases for one project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, frontend, backend

As I'm starting my carrier as JavaScript developer I always have this question. Let's say I'm developing an App using ReactJS. And in that project, I want to create separate domains for Admin and Client.

Because the admin can log into the backend and check the inventory, it won't get mixed with the Client / User when using the same login. And the code is also getting smaller

As an Example.

- Admin is logged using `admin.site.com`
- User / Client is logged in using `site.com/login`

Now, I decided to go with NodeJs as the back-end for the project. For front-end of the back-end (UI), I thought of using REactJS. Also to use Admin LTE.

For Client-side I will be also using ReactJs.

So there will be two ReactJS code bases and one Node JS.

My Questions are,

1. Is this method ok?
2. Or can I do this on one ReactJS code base?
3. Do you guys have any suggestions for me?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes. 3. You can use roles and permissions to grant/limit access to different parts of the site. Regarding going with 1 or 2, it depends on how different or similar the functionality is.

Comment: @Craicerjack what do you just from Question from 1 and 2? I mean what path should I go. Method I have asked or using a Single Code base?

Comment: I cant suggest anything. I dont know enough about what you are doing. These are the technical decisions you will encounter when building things. There are pros and cons to both. One of the prinicples of coding is DRY (dont repeat yourself), so...

Comment: @Craicerjack Thanks. I will do the experiment few projects in both ways. Thank you